# Tasks inside Interrupt Handler

Tags: stm32, c, embedded, interrupts, rtos

Is there any schedular that exists for STM32F103 in which the 'tasks' are run at the ISR() level while the Schedular() code runs in the main() thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel drivers work in the ISR. Tasks do not.
It is also impossible for ARM in OS configuration to perform a task switch in main due to thread vs privileged mode of the core registers.